# vuejs + vuetify + ssr + typescript: Error: bundle export should be a function when using { runInNewContext: false }

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-ssr

I've created a project with vue-cli (vue create) with typescript and less support.

After that I added vuetify (vue add vuetify). And everything worked as expected.

But after adding ssr (vue add @akryum/ssr) I get this error:

> Error: bundle export should be a function when using {
>   runInNewContext: false }

Error-Location: node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.dev.js:9353:14

I've tried creating a project without typescript and ssr is working.
Only when I add typescript, this error appears.

Is this a typescript configuration (tsconfig) problem or is the problem somewhere else?